# Struggling with my Bootstrap Navbar responsiveness

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I am struggling with the responsiveness of my Bootstrap navbar. I want the navbar to display all of the buttons in a row when on desktop, and as the viewport gets smaller for them to be collapsed under the fas fa-bars navbar toggler.

All required stylesheets and scripts have been linked.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
<!-- Header -->
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar sticky-top">
          <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
            <img class="huisie-logo" src="./Assets/Home logo with text yellow.svg" height="50" alt="Huisie Logo" loading="lazy">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-mdb-toggle="collapse" data-mdb-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <div class="nav-item d-flex flex-column">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-dark px-3 me-auto nav-item m-2">
              Find room
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-dark px-3 me-auto nav-item m-2">
              Make listing
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-dark px-3 me-auto nav-item m-2">
              Sign up
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-3 me-auto text-warning nav-item m-2">
              Log In
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      <!-- Navbar -->

    </div>
        
</header>
<!-- /Header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be `data-bs-target` and `data-bs-toggle`

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar sticky-top">
        <a href="" class="navbar-brand">
          <img class="huisie-logo" src="./Assets/Home logo with text yellow.svg" height="50" alt="Huisie Logo" loading="lazy">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <div class="nav-item d-flex flex-column">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-dark px-3 me-auto nav-item m-2">
              Find room
              </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-dark px-3 me-auto nav-item m-2">
              Make listing
              </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link text-dark px-3 me-auto nav-item m-2">
              Sign up
              </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-3 me-auto text-warning nav-item m-2">
              Log In
              </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- Navbar -->

    </div>
```